# jspdf error : Unable to look up font label

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, jspdf

I am trying to create pdf from table html with style by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060563/how-to-set-column-width-for-generating-pdf-using-jspdf/23385322#23385322) post.

But I got this error in jspdf.debug.js.

> Error: Unable to look up font label for font 'times ', 'bold'. Refer to getFontList() for available fonts.

I tried different font names and styles.

Comment: What do you get from `getFontList()`? Do you have any Times-like fonts at all?

Comment: @Rup. Yes. times font exist.

Comment: OK - can you try using a string that's exactly the same as one you get back from getFontList? You can see from your error message it has problems cutting the spaces in the right place, so try with a font that's a single word e.g. Arial if that's in the list. And just to be safe get the casing right - you've got lower-case 'T' in your error which the font won't be.

Comment: @Rup  I tried several fonts including arial with lower case and upper case. This error always rise.