# How to convert HTML to pdf in angular2?

Tags: angular, pdf, typescript, html-to-pdf

I need to convert Dynamic generated html table in to pdf and able to print it too. I need it to be done in angular2 and Typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate PDF file from html using angular2/typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996376/generate-pdf-file-from-html-using-angular2-typescript)

Comment: Have a look at jsPDF.

Comment: I have checked JsPDF it works with angular1 not with angular2. Can you show me something in plunker where we can convert HTML to pdf. I need to convert the HTML table with ID to pdf and print it.

Comment: It does work in angular 2. You need to get the `typings` for it of course.

Answer (score 7):

JSPDF works for angular 2. You need to download the definitions from dt~.
Import the library as:

```
import * as jsPDF from "jspdf";
.
.
.

let doc = new jsPDF();

// Add a title to your PDF
doc.setFontSize(30); 
doc.text(12, 10, "Your Title");

// Create your table here (The dynamic table needs to be converted to canvas).
let element = <HTMLScriptElement>document.getElementsByClassName("pvtTable")[0];
html2canvas(element)
.then((canvas: any) => {
    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), "JPEG", 0, 50, doc.internal.pageSize.width, element.offsetHeight / 5 );
    doc.save(`Report-${Date.now()}.pdf`);
})
```

In your system.js, in the map section add this line:

```
"jspdf": "<myLibs>/jspdf.js",
```

Comment: you are my hero.